# On EC2 - How can one instance telnet the other using ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX format

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, host

(Noob @ unix&EC2)

I created 2 ubuntu instances at EC2.
I needed to cluster one of my services and following the tutorial I used the format

```
ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX  (i.e.  ip-123-456-789-012) as the connection.
```

I can also telnet between the instances using ip-123-456-789-012 22.
This does not appear in /etc/hosts so how does it knows how to translate the string to an ip address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the name service/resolver system. The telnet utility will request a name to IP address translation. the resolver system will look at the [nsswitch.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf) file and get the hosts entry e.g.

```
hosts:      files dns
```

This says check the [hosts file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts) then if you don't have an answer check the DNS (there are other options too).

As you don't have anything configured in the hosts file the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) will be consulted. 
The resolver looks in the [resolv.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) file and gets the addresses of the DNS servers to query. It then asks the DNS server if it has the IP address to the hostname ...

Lots of research for you to do now you have some hints.

Answer (score 5):

[DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

[It is a CNAME to be exact.](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346)

<sub>*Stupid 30 character requirement*</sub>